# Docker Compose with Podman fails with "rootless port failed to add port: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use"

Tags: docker-compose, systemd, podman

I am trying to run Docker Compose with Podman in rootless mode and using systemd to run it at boot. I have `podman.socket` running successfully for my user, but when the systemd unit tries to run `docker-compose`, I get the following error when running `systemctl --user status docker-compose.service`

```
× docker-compose.service - Rootless docker compose
     Loaded: loaded (/home/haxney/.config/systemd/user/docker-compose.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-09-26 20:23:19 CDT; 3min 51s ago
    Process: 766 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 766 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 227ms

Sep 26 20:23:18 dagny systemd[729]: Started Rootless docker compose.
Sep 26 20:23:18 dagny docker-compose[766]: Starting docker_getting_started_1 ...
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny docker-compose[766]: Starting docker_getting_started_1 ... error
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny docker-compose[766]: ERROR: for docker_getting_started_1  port reloading failed: rootless port failed to add port: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny docker-compose[766]: ERROR: for getting_started  port reloading failed: rootless port failed to add port: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny docker-compose[766]: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny systemd[729]: docker-compose.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 26 20:23:19 dagny systemd[729]: docker-compose.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

## System info

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

$ docker version
Version:      3.4.4
API Version:  3.4.4
Go Version:   go1.17.3
Built:        Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 1969
OS/Arch:      linux/amd6

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.10.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

$ podman version
Version:      3.4.4
API Version:  3.4.4
Go Version:   go1.17.3
Built:        Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 1969
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

## Config files

My systemd unit file (`~/.config/systemd/user/docker-compose.service`) is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rootless docker compose
Wants=podman.socket
After=podman.socket

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=%h/docker
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose down -v

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and `~/docker/docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  getting_started:
    image: docker/getting-started
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
```

I also have `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock` in my `~/.profile`, so `docker-compose` commands use Podman correctly.

## State after boot

Immediately after boot, without making any other changes, this is what I get.

I can see that the service is down with `docker-compose ps`:

```
$ docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State        Ports    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_getting_started_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Exit 0   :8080->80/tcp
```

`sudo netstat -ntlp` gives:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      728/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      728/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Both `podman ps` and `docker ps` return an empty list:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
```

## `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up -d`

If I run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d`, then everything works and `docker/getting-started` is able to listen successfully:

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      728/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2302/containers-roo 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      728/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

## Restart with `systemctl`

However, on a fresh boot, if I run `systemctl --user restart docker-compose.service`, then I get the following status:

```
$ systemctl --user status docker-compose.service
● docker-compose.service - Rootless docker compose
     Loaded: loaded (/home/haxney/.config/systemd/user/docker-compose.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-09-26 20:50:50 CDT; 1s ago
   Main PID: 1713 (docker-compose)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18639)
     Memory: 23.0M
        CPU: 144ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/docker-compose.service
             └─1713 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/docker-compose up

Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.3
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-84-generic
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 17
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 18
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 19
Sep 26 20:50:51 dagny docker-compose[1713]: getting_started_1  | 2023/09/27 01:50:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
```

However, the port is not open:

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      731/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      622/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      731/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Both `docker ps` and `podman ps` return:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                    COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS            PORTS                 NAMES
5d84b5992cf2  docker.io/docker/getting-started:latest  nginx -g daemon o...  16 minutes ago  Up 3 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  docker_getting_started_1
```

And with `docker-compose`, I get:

```
$ docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State       Ports    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_getting_started_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      :8080->80/tcp
```

If I do:

```
$ docker-compose down
$ systemctl --user start docker-compose.service
```

Then I'm back to the same state as immediately post-boot.

## Question

It seems like systemd is actually running `docker-compose up`, but somehow it isn't running it in the correct way. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that I'm not happy about, but it is reliable.

Simply have the systemd unit config bring the stack up, then down, then up again. Here is the systemd unit file which works:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rootless docker compose
Wants=podman.socket
After=sockets.target podman.socket

[Service]
Type=oneshot

WorkingDirectory=%h/docker
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock

# For whatever reason, starting it, stopping it, and then starting it again
# works.
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f %h/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f %h/docker/docker-compose.yml down
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f %h/docker/docker-compose.yml up --remove-orphans -d

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I wish there was a more elegant way of doing this, but at least it works.